# Embedded Visualforce Page causing custom buttons to render beneath it and cut off the page

Tags: apex, visualforce, standard-objects

I have some very strange behavior on a newly created Visualforce Page that is embedded in a standard layout. Custom buttons for that page will appear directly beneath it and the Related Lists will appear below it (even if this embedded Visualforce page is at the top of the layout). When collapsing the Section block it will also hide the custom buttons

To help explain and illustrate the issue I have a few screenshots:

What the page appears in the Layout:
[image]

What the page looks like on its own:

[image: Standalone Layout]

What the editor looks like:
[image: page editor]

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" label="Should I Give Support?" extensions="Membership_Should_I_Support_Controller" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="true">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!all_okay==false}">
        <!-- Mostly standard HTML -->
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!all_okay==true}">
        <!-- Mostly standard HTML -->
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Did you mean to include the buttons in your VF page sample above?

Comment: Where are the Open Case, Reschedule Case and Survey buttons defined? Can you show a screen shot of the layout editor for the object. Sorry I'm a little confused now as to where these buttons are coming from. It would help to know a little more. Thanks.

Comment: The buttons are only defined in the case layout (where else can you put "custom buttons" outside of a VF page?). I edited the initial post with a screenshot of the editor

Comment: No other place than on a layout, its news to me how these buttons have moved from their usual place? Very interesting! Is the example screenshot from the Case detail page then? Can you include the full screenshot....

Comment: I included a full screenshot of the Case layout page now. I've never really seen this behavior before in SF.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this an i cannot, see my answer. Is there something else on your VF page perhaps? There is nothing special as far as I can see when configuring the layout section.

Comment: Ah....I've just spotted something on your layout designer..... it says "Should I give support? [BETA]", so this looks like some kind of new Case layout feature perhaps? Can you try creating a new section on the layout?

Comment: The "Should I Give Suppurt? [BETA]" is the section, that's just what I named it :P Tried a new section, same result

Comment: Oh wow, kept creating new sections with different names just to see if that was what was wrong, now when I hide the section, it hides all the related lists as well now :/ I think this might be a bug with Salesforce and not anything I've done wrong now....

Comment: Yeah agree, think we have both invested enough time trying to figure this one out. Well at least you can provide a lucky Salesforce support engineer with a nice summary of things you've tried! ;-) Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort Andrew, it has been much appricated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When embedding Visualforce pages in layouts the whole page, including everything on it is displayed in that section of the layout. The platform does not attempt to lift any buttons you have placed on the out and display them alongside the other buttons on the layout.

Hence your buttons just appear in that section and disappear when you collapse that section. To add buttons to layouts you need to create a [Custom Button](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=defining_custom_links.htm&language=en_US) and drag that onto the buttons section of the layout. This blog provides another resource describing how to [create such buttons with Apex](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/07/16/how-to-call-apex-code-from-a-custom-button/).

**Update: 11th Nov**

I must admit I'm starting to think the buttons your seeing are some kind of bug or hidden feature to render custom buttons on the section or somehow in the VF page? I've created a VF page for Case, put it on a layout with a custom button of my own and i don't see it replicated below the VF page layout section.

Ah....I've just spotted something on your layout designer..... it says **"Should I give support? [BETA]"**, so this looks like some kind of new Case layout feature perhaps? Can you try creating a new section on your layout instead of using this section?

[image]

Comment: The custom buttons appear at the top of page like they are supposed to, they are not meant to appear on the embedded visual force on the same standard object